# Express Validator: Custom validation with asynchronous functions

Tags: javascript, express, async-await, es6-promise, express-validator

I'm currently trying to validate some inputs in Express using [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/). I know that it's typical to pass it as a separate middleware into the route, but I needed access to the `res` object, so I had to write it in the way you see below.

The part that I'm struggling with is the `custom` validator. I'd like it to call an asynchronous function `store.todoListTitleExists(title)` that queries a database and checks if a title already exists. If the title doesn't exist, my intention is to save an error message which I can later display as a flash message.

Currently, this code doesn't work. I've looked through the documentation but I can't seem to figure out how to make this custom validator + error message work properly since it calls an asynchronous function. Any help would be apprecated.

Thanks!

```js
app.post("/lists/:todoListId/edit", 
    (req, res) => {
    let store = res.locals.store;
    let todoListId = req.params.todoListId;
    let title = req.body.todoListTitle;

    await body('todoListTitle')
          .trim()
          .isLength({ min: 1 })
          .withMessage("The list title is required.")
          .isLength({ max: 100 })
          .withMessage("The list title cannot be over 100 characters")
          .custom(store.todoListTitleExists(title).then(titleExists => {
            if(titleExists) return Promise.reject('Title already exists');
          }))
```

Comment: The better approach to it would be use of middleware which can intercept the req and then you can do other tasks ... Like `app.use(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `req` object in a custom validator function.

```js
const titleDuplicatesValidator = async (value, { req }) => {
    const exists = await store.todoListTitleExists(title);
    if (exists) throw new Error('Title already exists!');
}
```

And then pass that to your objects custom function.

```js
body('todoListTitle')
    .custom(titleDuplicatesValidator)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
body("feildName", "Feild must be selected")
.custom(value=> {

    titleExists=await store.todoListTitleExists(value)
    if(titleExists){
    Promise.reject('title exists')
    }
    return true


    return true

}),
```

Answer (score -1):

Express-validator is intended to sanitize and validate data being sent between the client and server. In order to handle this in a way that is scalable I would recommend using a file to handle all of your sites post requests (something like `routes.js` for example).

Here is a sample custom router that displays an error message if the validation fails :

```
body("feildName", "Feild must be selected")
    .custom(val => {

        if (val.feildName == "Select...") return false

        return true

    }),
```

Once you have isolated all routing to a specific file, you can add arguments like the example below for error messages to be served with the page (personnaly I use ejs templates so these error messages are displayed using the following code :

```
**controller.js**
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    const {
        body
    } = req;

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.render('index', {
            error: errors.array()[0].msg
        });
    }

    res.render("index");

**index.ejs**
<div class="error">
        <% if(typeof error !== 'undefined'){ %>
              <div class="err-msg"><%= error %></div>
        <% } %>
</div>
```